# Can I use the parameter in the function and echo it out in the if statement below

Tags: php, sql, function, variables

I am experiencing a problem where I can't use the parameter in the function in other functions more specifically the $studentnumber parameter, is it possible for the parameters used in other functions, the parameter used were dynamic parameter. I'm new to PHP so my terminology might be off I the end goal is to make $studentnumber, able to be used in other functions.

```
public function login($studentnumber, $password) {
            $conn = dbconnection();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE studentnumber = :studentnumber");
            $stmt->bindParam(':studentnumber', $studentnumber);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if ($password == $row['password']) {
                echo $studentnumber;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```
public function login($studentnumber, $password) {
            $this->studentnumber = $studentnumber;
            $conn = dbconnection();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE studentnumber = :studentnumber");
            $stmt->bindParam(':studentnumber', $studentnumber);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if ($password == $row['password']) {
                echo $this->studentnumber;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: store studentnumber in session then you can retrieve anywhere

Comment: There is a number of way to make the variable “available” to other functions. The one you you use will depend on your code structure/ use case. For example, if you are using php classes, you can assign the value to a class variable (private or public depending on which other functions need to use this) or you can use a public function to return the value. Or in a simplest form, you can return the value from login function (return $studentnumber instead of return true).

Comment: @smartdroid Thanks the functions, were inside a class, so I guess I assign it to a class variable. Should I consider doing saving it as a session variable or would that be bad practice?

Comment: If the variable changes within the code, then assigning it to a session variable is considered bad practice by some. But session variable will work in this case. My preference will be to assign it to a class variable.

Comment: @smartdroid I added $studentnumber as a public class variable, when I echo I still receive nothing? Is the something I'm missing?

Comment: How are you accessing the variable? You need to use $this->studentnumber